# What are are these css-files in Dev tools that can't be found on hard drive?

Tags: css, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

Here is screen-shot of Thunderbird's dev tools. I want to replace that highlighted yellow colour with something that would irritate my eyes less (I use dark theme for Thunderbird GUI).

[image: Screen-shot]

So, I created <thunderbird_profile>/chrome directory that hosts userChrome.css file. But I dont get which selector I write in there to have this yellow colour overriden? It seems the selector that sets this colour to locate in some kind of internal css (if I click the highlighted hyper-link, then I am redirected to something that looks like standard css, but all my attempts to find file with such name on hard drive to change it were in vain). What are those css-files and how can I override them?

Comment: those styles must be from library you are using.

Comment: It's inside `omni.ja` file in the app directory, it's a zip file.

Comment: It could also be coming from an extension

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! I have edited css-files within this archive and now GUI looks the way I want it to. Should you choose to convert your comment into an answer, I'd be delighted to accept it as the answer.